# Extracting values from nested JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I want to extract data from nested JSON in MySQL, for example:

```
create table json_test (my_json json);
insert into json_test values ('{"outer_key": {"inner_key": "inner_value"} }');
mysql> select * from json_test;
+---------------------------------------------+
| my_json                                     |
+---------------------------------------------+
| {"outer_key": {"inner_key": "inner_value"}} |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

I can extract one layer deep succesfully with:

```
select my_json -> '$.outer_key' from json_test;
```

But I'm unable to get the deepest value with what I was familiar with from Postgres:

```
select my_json -> '$.outer_key' -> '$.inner_key' from json_test; -- syntax error
select my_json -> '$.outer_key' ->> '$.inner_key' from json_test; -- syntax error
```

I figured out an ugly work around with:

```
mysql> with cte as (select my_json -> '$.outer_key' as cte_inner from json_test) select cte_inner -> '$.inner_key' from cte;
+----------------------------+
| cte_inner -> '$.inner_key' |
+----------------------------+
| "inner_value"              |
+----------------------------+
```

But was wondering if there was a simplier solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the [full path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax) like so:

```
select my_json->'$.outer_key.inner_key' from json_test;
-- "inner_value" (json)

select my_json->>'$.outer_key.inner_key' from json_test;
-- inner_value (string)
```

Comment: *-- "inner_value" (json)* It seems that this is not JSON but string-type value. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ad71fc85931b8a68f9eefe49be04154) - JSON is treated as binary string (which is detected by client) and hence is printed in HEX rather than extracted value.